# Having error while requesting wsdl file from grails

Tags: web-services, grails, soap, groovy, wsdl

I'm using:
Grails
xfire plugin
and I created the service mobile containing the following code:
**services/MobileService.groovy**

```
package survey

class MobileService {
    static expose=['xfire'];
    static transactional = true;
    Choice getChoices(String questionTitle_){
        return Questions.findByQuestionTitle(questionTitle_);
    }
}
```

**UrlMappings.groovy**

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                controller(matches:/.*[^(services)].*/)
            }
        }
        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

I can see XML content of WSDL file here:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/survey/services/mobile?wsdl
But I can't read it using my client and I'm having the following **error**:

> Error 2012-01-25 22:42:12,826 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-2] ERROR
>   [/survey].[XFireServlet]  - Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [XFireServlet] in context with path [/survey] threw exception Message:
>   No value for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@4af6178d]
>   bound to thread ["http-bio-8080"-exec-2]    Line | Method
>   ->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
>   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |   908 | run     in     '' ^   680 | run . . in java.lang.Thread

After changing the client it turned out that the SOAP server and client is working fine now.
That error wasn't effecting the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem and solution are described in [this jira](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCXF-3?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

Hack that works for me:

```
def doWithWebDescriptor = { xml ->
    def filters = xml.filter
    def filterMappings = xml.'filter-mapping'
    def servlets = xml.servlet
    def servletMappings = xml.'servlet-mapping'

    // define hibernate's OpenSessionInViewFilter
    def hibernateFilter = 'hibernateFilter'

    // Here's the modification I made per the JIRA:
    /*
    filters[filters.size()-1] + {
        filter {
            'filter-name'(hibernateFilter)
            'filter-class'('org.grails.xfire.OpenSessionInViewFilter')
        }
    }
    filterMappings[filterMappings.size()-1] + {
        'filter-mapping' {
            'filter-name'(hibernateFilter)
            'url-pattern'("/services/*")
        }
    }
    */

    def xfireServlet = 'XFireServlet'
    servlets[servlets.size()-1] + {
        servlet {
            'servlet-name'(xfireServlet)
            'servlet-class'('org.grails.xfire.XFireSpringServlet')
            'load-on-startup'(1)
        }
    }
    servletMappings[servletMappings.size()-1] + {
        'servlet-mapping' {
            'servlet-name'(xfireServlet)
            'url-pattern'("/services/*")
        }
    }
    servletMappings[servletMappings.size()-1] + {
        'servlet-mapping' {
            'servlet-name'(xfireServlet)
            'url-pattern'("/servlet/XFireServlet/*")
        }
    }
}
```